# Why does the Wii U display websites weirdly?

Tags: web, wii-u

So I was messing with my Wii U's web browser and found their cool little developer tools feature. I enabled it and loaded up my website.

While inspecting it, I found something weird - the website's `body` displays as 980 pixels wide, even though the gamepad is only 854 pixels wide according to [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wii_U_GamePad#Features).

If it matters, [here](http://georgeplatko.byethost22.com)'s a link to my site, but I'm pretty sure it's not my code that's doing this. Any ideas?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The viewport of the browser is 980 pixels wide. This is most often seen on mobile browsers, where emulating desktop dimensions would be troublesome; not sure why they would feel the need to do the same in this situation. Perhaps they ported an existing mobile browser? You can control this behaviour by [using the `<meta>` element](http://www.quirksmode.org/mobile/metaviewport/) on your website.

Comment: Not a problem at all.